# Cosmological redshift

Tags: cosmology, doppler-effect, gravitational-redshift

We have three of them (and combinations):

- gravitational, when light travels near masive object (red shift)
- Doppler's, when light is emited by moving object (red or blue)
- cosmological - all far objects seems to be redish

There is a commonly agreed hypotesis that the cosmological redshift means that space is expanding. In one hand it is quite intuitive, but in other hand a bit odd. You know, expansion seems to accelerate, but it is suspisiosly "lazy". I mean, it looks like the world we know in cosmological point of view, stands on the top of a pin and it wobbles.

Are there any studies that could disprove another hypothesis, that the cosmological one is caused by tiny "resistance" of huge amount of space, vacuum, distance? Sorry for the term "resistance", but it comes to my mind when I am thinking about the energy. Red light has less energy, than blue light and this energy difference could be a cost of long distances travel, not (or not only) a cost of an expansion.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tired_light
for the 'tired light' theory and falsified examples

Comment: Light traveling past massive objects to and from distant points isn't redshifted, just deflected. Gravitational redshift or blueshift depends only on the difference in escape velocity between point of emission and point of detection.

Comment: @gs I think this is about when light climbs out of a gravitational well of a massive object, and gets redshifted.

Comment: Come up with an actual hypothesis. How does your "resistance" change the wavelengths of all spectral features by the same factor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.